# GoogleTest linking error: 'undefined symbol' when using clang in MSVS

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, clang, googletest

I am having difficulty getting GoogleTest to compile on Windows with Clang, and keep getting `undefined symbol` errors.  What am I doing wrong?

I have two projects in this solution

1. a static library (cArray)
2. a application project (cArray_tests) that depends on cArray.lib

Both have the following config options under `Configuration Properties >> VC++ Directories >> Library Directories`

- C:...\GoogleTest\1.14.0\build\lib\Debug

...as well `Include Directories`:

- C:...\GoogleTest\1.14.0\googletest\include
- C:...\GoogleTest\1.14.0\googlemock\include

`Output` (in MSVS)

```
undefined symbol : void const* __cdecl testing::internal::GetTestTypeId(void)
undefined symbol : class testing::TestInfo* __cdecl testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, struct testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void(__cdecl*)(void), void(__cdecl*)(void), class testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)
undefined symbol : bool __cdecl testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)
undefined symbol : public: __cdecl testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(enum testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)
undefined symbol : public: __cdecl testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog(void)
undefined symbol : protected: __cdecl testing::Test::Test(void)
undefined symbol : public: __cdecl testing::Message::Message(void)
undefined symbol : public: __cdecl testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(enum testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)
undefined symbol : public: void __cdecl testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(class testing::Message const&) const
undefined symbol : public: __cdecl testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper(void)
undefined symbol : public: virtual __cdecl testing::Test::~Test(void)
undefined symbol : class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionSuccess(void)
undefined symbol : class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>> const&, class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>> const&, bool)
undefined symbol : protected: virtual void __cdecl testing::Test::SetUp(void)
undefined symbol : protected: virtual void __cdecl testing::Test::TearDown(void)
undefined symbol : void __cdecl testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)
undefined symbol : public: static class testing::UnitTest * __cdecl testing::UnitTest::GetInstance(void)
undefined symbol : public: int __cdecl testing::UnitTest::Run(void)
```

`cArray_tests.cpp`

```
#include "cArray.hpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

    namespace framework {
    namespace testing  {
    namespace          {
    
        class cArrayTest : public ::testing::Test 
        {
        protected:
            cArrayTest() {}
            ~cArrayTest() override {}
            void SetUp() override {}
            void TearDown() override {}
        };
    
        TEST(cArray, DefaultConstructor)
        {
            cArray<int> a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    
            //EXPECT_THAT(a1, ::testing::ElementsAre(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
            EXPECT_EQ(a1.size(), 7);
        }
    };
    };
    };
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "cArray.hpp"
#include "cArray_tests.cpp"


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for myself.  Like any good programmer I will post the solution to save any future programmers aggravation.

### Did not work:

1. Building *gtest* and *gmock* with **MSVS** and using just about every possible combination of compilers, compiler options, MSVS options

   - Same errors as in OP
2. Building *gtest* and *gmock* separately using **CMake**

   - Same errors as in OP

### Worked

3. Built WITH *gtest*/*gmock* as a dependency.

   - Navigate to project folder with `CMakeList.txt` and then in cmd: `cmake -S . -B build && cmake --build build && cd build && ctest`
   - **FIXED!!!**

`CMakeList.txt` (root CMakeList)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

# I. GLOBAL VARIABLES
##############################################################################
# Framework name
set(FRAMEWORK_NAME my_framework CACHE INTERNAL "") 

# project name and version: this is MY_FRAMEWORK
project(my_framework VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# set C standard to C17
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17 CACHE INTERNAL "") 
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON CACHE INTERNAL "")

# set C++ standard to C++20
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20 CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON CACHE INTERNAL "")

# Get framework root directory path
cmake_path(GET CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR PARENT_PATH ROOT_DIR)
cmake_path(GET ROOT_DIR PARENT_PATH ROOT_DIR)

# Set build, include, modules, source, resource, and test directories 
#     first get ${ROOT_DIR} (2 levels up, or the grandparent of current 
#     Use ${ROOT_DIR} to set path names
set(BUILD_DIR_ROOT      ${ROOT_DIR}/build               CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(INC_DIR_ROOT        ${ROOT_DIR}/inc                 CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(MODULES_DIR_ROOT    ${ROOT_DIR}/modules             CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(RES_DIR_ROOT        ${ROOT_DIR}/res                 CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(SRC_DIR_ROOT        ${ROOT_DIR}/src                 CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(TEST_DIR_ROOT       ${ROOT_DIR}/test/unit_tests     CACHE INTERNAL "")

# Set Windows DLL includes
#     required to make Windows library files (*.dll)
set(DLL_HEADERS
    ${INC_DIR_ROOT}/build/dll/framework.h
    ${INC_DIR_ROOT}/build/dll/pch.h
CACHE INTERNAL "")

############ GOOGLE TEST
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  SOURCE_DIR D:/name/code/libraries/GoogleTest/1.14.0
)

# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()
include(GoogleTest)

#macros
etc...
```

`CMakeList.txt` (non-root, module-specific CMakeList)

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../CMakeLists.txt)

# project name and version
project(my-array VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(MODULE_NAME cArray)
set(MODULE_PATH util/array)

# set module build, include, source, resource, and test directories (resp.)
set(BUILD_DIR   ${BUILD_DIR_ROOT}/${MODULE_PATH})
set(INC_DIR     ${INC_DIR_ROOT}/${MODULE_PATH})  
set(MODULE_DIR  ${MODULES_DIR_ROOT}/${MODULE_PATH}/${MODULE_NAME})
set(RES_DIR     ${RES_DIR_ROOT}/ ${MODULE_PATH})  
set(SRC_DIR     ${SRC_DIR_ROOT}/${MODULE_PATH})  
set(TEST_DIR    ${TEST_DIR_ROOT}/${MODULE_PATH}/${MODULE_NAME})

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin CACHE INTERNAL "")

# set project header files (.../root/inc/${MODULE_PATH}/.hpp)
set(PROJECT_HEADERS
    ${INC_DIR}/cArray.hpp
)

# set project source files (.../root/src/${MODULE_PATH}/.cpp)
set(PROJECT_SOURCE
    ${SRC_DIR}/cArray.cpp
)

# set project test files (.../root/test/${MODULE_PATH}/.cpp)
set(PROJECT_TESTS    
    ${TEST_DIR}/cArray_tests.cpp
    ${MODULE_DIR}/cArrayImpl.cpp
    ${MODULE_DIR}/main.cpp
)

###############################################################################
# II. TESTS    ###############################################################################
add_executable(
  cArray-tests
  ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE}
  ${PROJECT_TESTS}
)

# 
set_target_properties(cArray-tests PROPERTIES   
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.todo.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(
  cArray-tests
  GTest::gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(cArray-tests)
```

https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html got me here...
Ironically, I turned to the quickstart article long after much more-detailed modules failed to fix the problem.  In other words, none of the other official GoogleTest documentation had this minimum working example.